# Android: Problems with Timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I've got some code like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button StartButton;
    private Button StopButton;
    private Timer timer;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //some code
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(task, 0, interval);
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

The problem is when onDestroy() is called the timer thread keeps working, but the link to timer object is lost, so I can't control it any more. How can I keep the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Timer to work even after the `Activity` is destroyed, then you should not tie the Timer to the Activity life-cycle. Use a `Service` to control the Timer, since your intention is to keep the timer working/running even after the `Activity` is destroyed. The `Services` are meant to be used for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Stop your timer in onDestroy. Try the code below.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I need the timer working background, so that's not an option for me.